# Scaling a video fails

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libav

I am using `avconv` to scale a video to a lower size. I just want to make video width smaller, and allow height to adjust automatically with the width to keep proportions same. After the command, a file of 0 byte is produced only.

`$ avconv -i 20151113062553.mp4 -vf scale=320:-1 20151113062553_o.mp4`

Here's the output.

```
avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '20151113062553.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 2015-11-13 06:25:53
  Duration: 00:02:51.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15653 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 15506 kb/s, PAR 65536:65536 DAR 16:9, 27.72 fps, 90k tbn
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-13 06:25:53
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-11-13 06:25:53
[libx264 @ 0x765140] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x765140] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x765140] profile High, level 1.3
[libx264 @ 0x765140] 264 - core 142 r2389 956c8d8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.25 aq=1:1.00
encoder 'aac' is experimental and might produce bad results.
Add '-strict experimental' if you want to use it.
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Add `-strict experimental` as it says. ffmpeg creates the output file, but doesn't start writing to it because you have specified an experimental codec (native aac encoder) without signalling the relaxed standards compliance that ffmpeg needs to use it.

Recent builds of ffmpeg do not need `-strict experimental`, because the native aac encoder is no longer marked as experimental.

Comment: One liners are considered low quality post. If  you can elaborate a bit more, you may have an answer

Comment: That error message might also imply it is "re encoding" the audio.  As a sidenote, recent versions of FFmpeg have an "improved" aac encoder and you don't need the experimental flag anymore for it.

Comment: Since no copy switches are specified, avconv is indeed trying to encode audio. Most likely, none of the 3rd party AAC encoders are compiled/linked and the OP's March 2015 build reverts to the native encoder which fails because of the lack of `-strict -2`.

Comment: BTW, I posted a gdigrab Q [here](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2874). which you might be able to help with.